# How to set route path in spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Following is my servlet

```
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have different controllers in **controllers** package. I want to set the route path in spring
like

when user enter

**product/index**

it should go to **productControllers** and **index** method of get/post type.

how to set the route mapping in spring framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a  class level and method level `@RequestMapping` annotations as below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product")
public class ProductController{

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getProducts")
    public String getProducts() {
        //your business logic
        return "getProducts";
    }
}
```

Then a request to `http://localhost:8080/<context-root>/product/index` in your local environment will return a `welcome.jsp` page.

Similarly `http://localhost:8080/<context-root>/product/getProducts` will return `getProducts.jsp` page.

If your have one more controller `OrderController` and a method `getOrder` in it, you can add the class level annotation `@RequestMapping('/order')` and method level annotation `@RequestMapping('/getOrder')` so that the URL `http://localhost:8080/<context-root>/order/getOrder` will invoke the `getOrder` controller method

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@RequestMapping("web/service")` annotations on method you want to execute for that path:

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeService
{
   @RequestMapping("/welcome")
   public void welcomeMethod()
   {
       // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: what im asking that the welcomemethod should be opened when user open this link ...."site.com/Welcome/welcomemethod". how to do that ?

Comment: The path is to consider relative to the web app root

Comment: actually the example you provided will always open the welcomemethod on /welcome. but what i want like this /controllerName/welcome should open this link.